# Javascript: How to cache small MP3 file for offline play?

Tags: javascript

I'm building an alarm web app that needs to work offline. How can I cache the small mp3 ringtone so that the alarm still sounds when the app is offline?

Comment: you can use localstorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache using webSQL, indexdb, localstorage, or a cookie. I think using the localstorage would be the simplest solution.

Simple add an appdata.manifest file which has the ringtones you want to store. 
then in the html tag add

```
<html lang="en" manifest="appdata.manifest">
```

the cache file

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK: 
/page.html
CACHE:
# v0
# This file will tell the broweser what needs to be Cached
# Spaces are ignored
# Blank Lines are ignored
/music/music.mp3
```

Comment: I guess you also could just inline the audio data `<audio src="data:audio/mp3;base64,<encoded-file-contents>"></audio>`

Comment: Yes but you would still need to cache the main page.